# Can a register be considered a sequential circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, register, sequential-logic

If you build a 2-bit register with JK flip-flops with the objective to allow storing the bit that was last added, can this be considered a sequential circuit?

Comment: What is your definition for a sequential circuit, and does your register fit that definition or not?

Comment: "Sequence of the events occurring at the circuit inputs. Examples of such circuits include clocks, flip-flops, bi-stables, counters, memories, and registers" - this was the definition that made more sense to me that I could find which in this case I think I can consider what I have built a sequential circuit

Comment: You might want to look up the definition of Mealy and Moore state machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output in a combinational logic circuit depends **only** on the current value of the inputs. In other words, it has no state behaviour/storage of values/history.

The output in a sequential logic circuit can depend on the current input, **and** historical input/output values. In other words, the circuit has some element that stores the past state.

So to answer the question, you must consider: Can your circuit with two J-K flip-flops store the history of a previous state of the inputs?